# sum of reciprocals of composite squarefree numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

Let $a_n$ denote the $n$-th composite squarefree number.

Then
$$
\sum_n\frac{1}{a_n^s} = \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}-1-P(s)
$$
for $s>1$ (in fact, for $Re(s)>1$)

source and details:

https://oeis.org/A120944

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeZetaFunction.html

---

Question:
what is the value of $\sum\frac{1}{a_n}$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{a_{n}^{s}}=\frac{\zeta\left(s\right)}{\zeta\left(2s\right)}-1-P\left(s\right)
 $$ we have $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{a_{n}}=\lim_{s\rightarrow1}\left(\frac{\zeta\left(s\right)}{\zeta\left(2s\right)}-1-P\left(s\right)\right)
 $$ and now since $\zeta\left(s\right)\sim\frac{1}{s-1}$ and $P\left(s\right)\sim\log\left(\frac{1}{s-1}\right)$ when $s\rightarrow 1$ we can observe that the series diverges.

The most rapid way to prove the divergence is observing that $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{a_{n}}>\sum_{p>2}\frac{1}{2p}
 $$ since obviously every number in the form $2p,\, p>2$ is a composite squarefree number and since the series of the reciprocal of primes diverges we can conclude.

Answer (score 5):

A partial sum of terms with denoms $\le N$ is bounded below by the sum-over-semiprimes

$$\sum_{p<q\le \sqrt{N}}\frac{1}{pq}=\frac{1}{2}\left( \big(\sum_{p\le\sqrt{N}}1/p\big)^2-\sum_{p\le\sqrt{N}}1/p^2 \right), $$

which diverges since $\sum_{p\le\sqrt{N}}1/p$ diverges and $\sum_{p\le\sqrt{N}}1/p^2$ converges.

It occurs to me Marco's answer eclipses this one in terms of simplicity. However, it is generally useful to know that $(\sum_{i\in I} a_i)^2=(\sum_{i\in I}a_i^2)+\sum_{i,j\in I} a_i a_j$. And perhaps this argument can be taken further to get an asymptotic expansion of the partial sum as a function of $N$.

Comment: How can this be correct since the square-free numbers may involve more than two prime factors? Could you please explain your idea a little more?

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas Fixed argument.

Answer (score 4):

The sum diverges at $s = 1$. This is visible from the exporession you wrote down from the pole of the zeta function at $s = 1$.

You can heuristic it by thinking of the fact that about $6/\pi^2$ of all natural numbers are square-free [in the asymptotic density sense], so this sum should diverge at about the same rate as $\sum \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: AFAIK $\zeta(1)=\infty$ but also $P(1)=\infty$, so there is an undefined difference $\infty-\infty$ when taking $s=1$ in the formula.

Comment: @user340508 This isn't about plugging in $s=1$ and getting $\infty$ but considering the rate of divergence of the finite series at $s=1$.  The rate of divergence of $\sum_{p\le n} 1/p$ is about $O(\log \log n)$ so it diverges much much slower than the harmonic series.

Comment: @user340508 From the wikipedia link in your OP on prime zeta, as $s\to 1$ the $P(s)$ is only as large as $\log \zeta(s)$.